# What is the meaning of 'bear' in this context?

Tags: meaning

"The year which has passed… has not, indeed, been marked by any of those striking discoveries which at once revolutionise, so to speak, the department of science on which they bear"

Answer (score 1):

It's flipped around, but it's the phrasal verb "bear on," [defined below by Oxford, as shown on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+bear+on).

> bear on
>
> phrasal verb of bear
>
> 1.be relevant to something.
>
> *"two kinds of theories bear on literary studies"*